# Is there possible way to make this diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

Hello everybody,

I want to make this diagram but I dont know how to do and where to start.
I have thought about tikz already but I don't know anything about that.
Do we need to use tikz or there is a possible way to define a operator?
I want three line at the middle will be treated as a single formula and connected.

`$...1 \ -\thinskip- \ 1...$`

There are some idea I can catch, but I don't know which one is suitable for this.

- use table and do like @MadyYuvi's
- use matrix. but is there any way to define a group of arrows as an operator or not?
- use image. modify image and import to tex file. this is the way I usually do.
- use tikz. I actually want to learn but don't know which material is the easiest to start.

Thank you.

Comment: This really isn't a "please do this for me" type of site.  Look into a tikz tutorial.  If you run into a problem, bring your best attempt and we'll be happy to help.

Comment: @Teepeemm: I am sorry if my words let you think that way. I just hope there is some ways to do this without using tikz. To be good at tikz that takes plenty of time. I don't need you to believe me, but I dare say that I work harder than any other colleague I've ever known. My English is not really good, even my reply to your comment is quite slow. I need time to improve, and I don't need anyone to do it all for me, just need suggestions.

Comment: The matrix environment is similar to the tabular of MadyYuvi's.  In addition to your mentioned approaches, there is also xymatrix and the native picture environment (I believe picture is what xymatrix and tikz use in their code).  All of the approaches will involve some intimidating syntax to learn, but it's really not too bad.  Just get started.

Comment: It's the arrows that are really the problem.  If you're willing to separate them out so that they don't start from the exact same location and instead use $\nearrow$, $\searrow$, $\swarrow$, and $\nwarrow$, then you could do it all with a gather environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for fun, with `tikz-cd`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={-stealth}]
 & \mathbf{1} \arrow[dash,dash pattern=on 1em off 1ex,-,r] & \mathbf{1} & \\
 P^{1,n} \arrow[ur,start anchor=east] \arrow[r,start anchor=east] \arrow[dr,start anchor=east]
 & \mathbf{1} \arrow[dash,dash pattern=on 1em off 1ex,-,r] & \mathbf{2} & 
 P^{n+1}\arrow[ul,start anchor=west] \arrow[l,start anchor=west] \arrow[dl,start
 anchor=west]\\
 & \mathbf{2} \arrow[dash,dash pattern=on 1em off 1ex,-,r] & \mathbf{2} & \\ 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Much thanks for this suggestion, this is 100 times better than mine... :-D

Comment: @MadyYuvi Thanks! But I do not think we should say one code is better as another. I like your post, and upvoted it before writing this, which is for fun,

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat: Thank you so much. I will try and ask you some more about this. I want to understand more to do by myself.

Answer (score 3):

Below may helpful to you, but I believe some experts will give better suggestions:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array,multirow,rotating}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c c c}
1 &{-}{-} &1\\
\multirow{3}{*}{%
\rlap{\begin{picture}(0,0)(0,0)
\put(-30,12){\hbox to 2pc{\rightarrowfill}}
\put(-30,12){\rotatebox{25}{\hbox to 2pc{\rightarrowfill}}}
\put(-30,12){\rotatebox{-25}{\hbox to 2pc{\rightarrowfill}}}
\end{picture}
\smash{\rotatebox{180}{\begin{picture}(0,0)(65,17)
\put(0,0){\hbox to 2pc{\rightarrowfill}}
\put(0,0){\rotatebox{25}{\hbox to 2pc{\rightarrowfill}}}
\put(0,0){\rotatebox{-25}{\hbox to 2pc{\rightarrowfill}}}
\end{picture}}}
}}1 &{-}{-} &2\\
2 &{-}{-} &2
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank for your answer. I learned some things from your post.